# Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have a sequence s.t.:

> $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$

Is it true to say that approaching from negative infinity will give the same $L$?

Comment: If there is no reasoning then it is impossible to check its correctness.

Comment: "Approaching **from** negative infinity or **going to** negative infinity? If it is the latter it should be obvious that the limits at different points might be different. If the former, you will have to explain what "approaching from" something **means**!

Comment: Sequences are normally defined to be a map from the natural numbers (or some subset), so it doesn't make sense to approach negative infinity because the terms of a sequence have a starting point by the above definition.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean "approaching <strike>from</strike> negative infinity".

No, this is not true. For example consider
$$
f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x).
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \text{something else}.
$$